# Convert HTML table to CSV via PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table, export-to-csv

I am trying to pull each td element from the html table below and import each element into its own cell in a CSV file.

Here are the two html tables:

```
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#006699">
<tr align="center" class="tableRow1Font">
<td width="7%">WAITLIST</td>
<td width="5%">91630</td>
<td width="11%">
ACCY <A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~bulletin/ugrad/accy.html#2001" target="_blank">2001</A>
</td>
<td width="5%">10</td>
<td width="16%">Intro Financial Accounting</td>
<td width="6%">3.00</td>
<td width="8%"> Zou, Y</td>
<td width="8%"><A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~map/building.cfm?BLDG=DUQUES" target="_blank"
>DUQUES</a> 251</td>
<td width="13%">TR<br>09:35AM - 10:50AM</td>
<td width="14%">
01/13/14 - 04/28/14
</td>
<td width="7%">
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#006699">
<tr align="center" class="tableRow2Font">
<td width="7%">WAITLIST</td>
<td width="5%">90003</td>
<td width="11%">
ACCY <A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~bulletin/ugrad/accy.html#2001" target="_blank">2001</A>
</td>
<td width="5%">11</td>
<td width="16%">Intro Financial Accounting</td>
<td width="6%">3.00</td>
<td width="8%"> Zou, Y</td>
<td width="8%"><A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~map/building.cfm?BLDG=DUQUES" target="_blank" 
>DUQUES</a> 254</td>
<td width="13%">TR<br>11:10AM - 12:25PM</td>
<td width="14%">
1/13/14 - 04/28/14
</td>
<td width="7%">                                     
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have written code that goes through the tables and pulls the td elements:

```
    foreach($html->find('tr[align=center] td') as $e)
    $str .= strip_tags($e->innertext) . ', ';
    echo $str;
```

So how can I extract these elements into a CSV file? In Excel I want it to look like this with each td element in its own cell, starting a new row for each html table:

```
WAITLIST  91630  ACCY 2001  10  Intro Financial Accounting  3.00  Zou, Y  DUQUES 251  TR  
WAITLIST  90003  ACCY 2001  11  Intro Financial Accounting  3.00  Zou, Y  DUQUES 251  TR
```

Comment: have you looked into [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/fputcsv) ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a library exist for this. Goto http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/. Download the zip file and in example you would find 17html.php try this code. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

CSV means Comma Separated Values. Thus, as you echo out the data (after running it through your function to strip the `<td>` tags), put commas in between each piece of data (cell), and a new line where you want the next line to start.

So to use your example above, it should look like this:

```
WAITLIST,91630,ACCY,2001,10,Intro Financial Accounting,3.00,Zou,Y,DUQUES,251,TR
WAITLIST,90003,ACCY,2001,11,Intro Financial Accounting,3.00,Zou,Y,DUQUES,2,
```

Keep in mind that when you `echo` this, you shouldn't have any other html tags or anything.

Comment: One also needs to look into some [requirements](http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm). I had many difficulties building simplest CSVs only to find that most applications are too picky